# add directory pantheon files

Tags: pantheon

I 'm new to Elementary OS , I'm adapting to the desktop and to their way of seeing things "I have a few questions . :
One is whether there is any way to put a new folder in the area of personal directories Files Pantheon [image]
 , I wanted to put a new one that "Work" is called, know how I can do.
The other question is if I set for documents showing the type icon extension instead of a preliminary vistra .

A greeting.

Answer (score 2):

Click on "Carpeta Personal", create your Work file in Home (or wherever you want). Then right-click that new file and left click on Bookmark (or for you it's probably "Marcador" or something like that). Then it should be available on the left-hand panel.

I made a little slideshow for you: https://goo.gl/photos/Zvk4KbZ3iMnHkJH36

Comment: ok,  thank you very much for the help and making the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag and drop the folder too. Just look for the cursor to have a green plus sign and a line to appear indicating where in the list the folder will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the folder you want to add and left click 'bookmark' in the menu that appears.